# Deformations of genus g curves to 'non-reduced rational curve'

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes

We work over the complex numbers. Fix a genus $g$. Does there exist a connected reduced base $ B $ and a flat projective family $ \pi : X \rightarrow B $ satisfying the following two conditions?

1. its general fiber is a nonsingular curve of genus $ g $.
2. it has a special fiber $ X_0 $ which is an irreducible, projective one-dimensional scheme such that $ (X_0)_\text{red} $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{P}^1$.

Toy cases: If $ g $ is a triangular number, write $ g = \frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2} $ and we can take the universal family of degree $ d $ hypersurfaces in $ \mathbb{P}^2 $. If $ g = 4 $, we can take the family of complete intersections of type $ (2,3) $ in $ \mathbb{P}^3 $. This family has a fiber whose reduction is the twisted cubic. Similarly, if $ g=5 $, complete intersections of type $ (2,2,2) $ in $ \mathbb{P}^4 $ work. I don't know what happens for genera which can never occur as genera of complete intersection curves in projective space, say $ g=2,7,8 \dotsc $, although I think these occur as intersections in other varieties such as Grassmanians / products of projective spaces.

Comment: Embed your curve in projective space and use a torus action to specialize to a multiple line.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP is looking for *some* curve of genus g for each g not every curve of that genus. Another example is to take a type (2, g+1) divisor on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and deform it to a double line

Comment: @BenC "... and deform it to a double line"  If $g+1$ is odd, how can you deform a divisor of type $(2,g+1)$ to the double of a divisor?

Comment: @Jason Starr that's what I don't understand as well. Can you please explain what to do in your first comment? I thought of it but I don't know torus actions very well.

Comment: @JasonStarr you're right, what I said only works if $g$ is odd. In that case, I can choose a smooth divisor $D$ of type $(1, \tfrac{g + 1}{2})$ and then deform $2D$ to get a smooth divisor of type $(2,g)$ which then has genus $g$ while $D$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. I guess this strategy should work if I can write $g = (a-1)(b-1)$ with $a$ dividing $b$ but I didn't think hard enough about the numerology when I said my example.

Comment: In the case of even genus, you can consider plane curves of degree $d$ with a point of multiplicity $d-2$ at a specified point of the plane.  These specialize to double rational curves.